# Sending multiple emails from within Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

On Orbeon Forms 4.8, I've rebuilt email-form.xpl so that it constructs different emails depending on various conditions in the form. That works nicely, and it's even embedding form information in the emails it creates. I've got to the point where I have created a nicely structured set of  structures, as expected by the Orbeon Email processor. They are all wrapped up in a  tag, so I have something like ....

When it comes to actually calling the email processor, I need to work through that XML structure calling the email processor for one message at a time. The code below is what I have to do this and I can see from the debug that it is receiving my messages correctly, but once I check inside the processor all of the XML tags have been stripped away, and the email processor won't accept the input (which I know would only send the first message if it worked at all) because it says it is an incomplete content model.

```
<p:processor name="oxf:pipeline">
    <p:input
        name="config"
        href="#messages"
        transform="oxf:unsafe-xslt"
        debug="LOOPING THROUGH EMAIL MESSAGES - MESSAGES">
        <p:config xsl:version="2.0">
            <p:param type="input" name="messages"/>

            <xsl:message>
                XXXXX
                <xsl:value-of select="messages/message"/>
                XXXXX
            </xsl:message>

            <xsl:for-each select="/*/message">
                <p:processor name="oxf:email">
                    <p:input name="data">
                        <message>
                            <xsl:value-of select="messages/message"/>
                        </message>
                    </p:input>
                </p:processor>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p:config>
    </p:input>
</p:processor>
```

Clearly I did something wrong, but I don't see what it was.

Answer (score 0):

To print the XML via XSLT, use `<xsl:copy-of>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>`. The latter always takes the *string value* of the XML, which only looks at the text nodes. The former makes a copy of the XML tree.

The email processor can only send one email at a time. So What's needed is iterating over the `<message>` elements you have created via XSLT. The iteration must be done in XPL, so you must use [`<p:for-each>`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-pipeline-language-xpl#TOC-p:for-each-element).